# CCFileUtils: transition from class methods in Cocos2D-iphone 1.x to instance methods in Cocos2D 2.x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

As you probably know, all class methods of CCFileUtils in Cocos2D-iphone 1.x were rewritten as instance methods of the singleton [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] in Cocos2d 2.x, so instead of

`[CCFileUtils fullPathFromRelativePath:... resolutionType:...]`

we need to use

`[[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] fullPathFromRelativePath:maskFileName resolutionType:&resolution]`

I've written an extension for masking sprites (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/30494), which uses CCFileUtils heavily and now need to make it compatible with both cocos2d 1.x and 2.x

I know about CC_ENABLE_DEPRECATED flag which helps to translate those calls on the fly, but i'd like to have a clear solution. Something like a class method which will return me an id for use it like this:

```
Method:
+ (id) getCCFileUtils
{
id fileUtils = [CCFileUtils class];
if ([fileUtils instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(fullPathFromRelativePath:resolutionType:)])
{
    return [fileUtils sharedFileUtils];
}
else
{
    return fileUtils;
}
}
Usage:
id myFileUtils = [MyClass getCCFileUtils];

[myFileUtils fullPathFromRelativePath:maskFileName resolutionType:&resolution]

}
```

For sure, I get an error "No known instance method for selector 'sharedFileUtils'" in Cocos 1.x, because there is no such selector. How should i rewrite it to get working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i did it myself after sleeping a bit :)
Share the code:

```
/**In Cocos2d v 2.0 CCFileUtils class methods were moved to instance methods.
 Here we set SSK_FILE_UTILS to class or instance depending on Cocos2D version.
 */
#ifdef COCOS2D_VERSION
    #if COCOS2D_VERSION >= 0x00020000
        #define SSK_FILE_UTILS [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils]
    #else 
        #define SSK_FILE_UTILS CCFileUtils
    #endif
#else
    #define SSK_FILE_UTILS nil
#endif
```

Usage:

```
[SSK_FILE_UTILS fullPathFromRelativePath:... resolutionType:...]
```